# ValueError at /post/18/

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I learn django, and I do the Django girls' tutorial. (https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/fr).
When I try to see the text ,even if i'm not register, I have the edit views. And when I click on save, it send to me this message[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wl9z.png)

I want just to see the text when I'm not register and have not the edit views.
I hope you can help me
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .forms import PostForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect

# Create your views here.
def post_list(request):
    posts= Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts' : posts})
def post_detail(request, pk):
    #Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form':form})
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post.pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
    form = PostForm(instance=post)  
    form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
    form = PostForm(instance=post)
```

post_edit.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% block content %}
            <h2>New post</h2>
            <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </form>

        {% endblock %}
    {%endif%}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to filter by user, You cannot assign the entire user object to post.author. Thats where your error occurs. To identify individual authors consider using `post.author = request.user.id`